# Is existence a necessary condition for thinking?

Tags: epistemology, descartes, skepticism

Is existence a necessary condition for thinking?

Descartes argues that because he thinks, he exists. 
But wouldn't he have to exist in the first place for him to: 
 
A) Think and 
 
B) Realize that he thinks? 
So generally, is existence a necessary prerequisite of being able to think and know?

Comment: It's clearly not a sufficient condition because lots of things exist that can't think.

Comment: @curiousdannii question was edited, try again

Comment: It doesn't matter what is "in the first place" for making an inference. If smoke needs fire "in the first place" (let's say), then the presence of fire can be inferred from the presence of smoke. And yes, existence is a necessary "condition" for doing anything else.

Comment: I would agree that all he needed to do was say 'I Am'.

Comment: The " cogito" by itself does not mean that the ego has to think in order to exist. The " cogito" deals with propositions ( in the context of the search for a first absolute certan proposiiton capable of grounding knowledge in a 100% secure way) . The " cogito" means that (1) the proposition " I doubt" is certain (2) so, the proposition " I think" is certain, which implies the certainty of the proposition " I am" ( = first principle). But the relation of logical implication is not the same thing as the causal relation.

Comment: Nevertheless, once the " cogito" has been performed, Descartes takes more risks and says " I am, precisely speaking, nothing else than a thinking substance", which suggests that thinking is not only sufficient but also necessary for me to exist. Reference : *Meditations* , II So, in the end, Descartes  is not far from " not only I am if I think ( " cogito") but also, I am only if I think; in such a way that I am an immaterial being, a spiritual entity ". Descartes  may have fallen into a metaphysical paralogism.

Comment: Without a clear definition of 'existence', debate is useless. I would use this concept: 'an object exists for a subject if the subject can interact with it'. Therefore, _nothing exists per se_, but _for someone, if he can think of it_. In such case, thinking is necessary for existence. Otherwise, considering that two rocks can mutually interact, that does not necessarily mean that they exist. They can only exist as objects for the observer subject who is qualifying such process as interaction. Again, existence depends on a thinking mind.

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at a simplistic version of Descartes argument.

```
If I Think Then I Exist
I Think
 -------------------
Therefore I Exist
```

The exact same argument, but with more words:

```
If I think Then I must exist in the first place
I think
 ------------------
I must exist in the first place
```

That existence is a necessary condition for thinking is what Descartes argues. He makes the inference from thinking to existing from the fact that existence is a necessary condition for thinking - that is, it is a necessary condition that something must exist in order for it to think.  And since be is a think'n, he must be a existn'